# Bash here-documents and shebang lines

Tags: shell-script, here-document, shebang

Is it true to conclude that when using a bash here-doc like `bash << HEREDOC`, then always and without exceptions, shebang lines like `#!/bin/bash -x` are redundant?

If I would have to bet, I would bet that yes, they will be redundant, and could only use us to organize the information, like a sign saying for new users "the following set of commands was originally executed from a traditional script, don't run them in one line with double ampersands or another similar way".

I wonder what the experts say - Is the bash shebang line really are totally redundant when using a here-doc?

Comment: I wonder what you mean by "double ampersands"?

Comment: Hi, I mean to `&&`.

Comment: Ah, I was confused. My brain thought "asterisks".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in this case.

Summary: The hash-bang line (also called "shebang" and other things) is only ever needed if it's in an executable script that is run without explicitly specifying its interpreter (just as when executing a binary executable file).

In the case of your code, you're explicitly running the script within the here-document with `bash` already. There's no need to add the hash-bang as it will be treated as a comment.

Since the here-document script seems to want to be executed with the `-x` option set (judging from `#!/bin/bash -x`), you will have to use `set -x` inside the here-document to get the same effect as if running the here-document as its own script, again, because the hash-bang is treated as a comment.

The hash-bang line is used when executing an executable text file. The line tells the system what interpreter to use to execute it, and optionally allows you to specify one argument to that interpreter (`-x` in your case).

You *do* need the hash-bang there if you're writing the here-document to a file that will later be used as a script. For example:

```
cat >myscript.sh <<<END_OF_SCRIPT
#!/bin/bash
# contents of script
# goes here
END_OF_SCRIPT
```

Such a file also has to be made executable (`chmod +x myscript.sh`). But again, if you were to explicitly execute that script with `bash`, for example through

```
$ bash ./myscript.sh
```

or

```
$ bash -x ./myscript.sh
```

(or equivalently from within another script) then no hash-bang is needed, and the script would not have to be made executable.

It all comes down to how you would want to execute the script.

See also the Wikipedia entry for [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: Hi, you say "Yes, in this case". Can you clarify what particular case you mean to, or you mean globally ?...

Comment: I mean that in this case you're not running the script (in the here-doc) as an executable from the command line. You are in fact specifically saying "run this with `bash`". So, in this case, the shebang will just be a comment in the script. But, as I wrote, if the script in the here-doc was written to a file (`cat >myscript.sh <<END_OF_SCRIPT`), then the shebang would be needed, and the script would need to be made executable. It all comes down to how you plan to run the script in the here-doc.

Comment: I thank you dearly for the answer and detailing!

Comment: "The hash-bang line is used when executing an executable text file from the shell. The line tells the shell what interpreter to use to execute" => No, the shell does not analyze the file. The first line is read by the _kernel_ when the script is executed as a stand-alone executable (i.e. `./my_script.sh` vs `/bin/shell my_script.sh`), whatever executes it (not only the shell but any call to the `execve()` system call).

Comment: @xhienne You're right. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you. There remain two superfluous "from the shell" in your answer.

Comment: @xhienne It's nitpicking, but I'll fix it.

Comment: I'm a proud nitpicker. Thanks and happy new year @Kusalananda

Comment: @Kusalananda, I humbly recommend edit the answer in accordance with the clarification you gave me here about "in this case"...

Comment: @Benia done, I think.

Comment: I meant to edit this in the very start of the answer... Replacing the phrase "Yes, in this case" with a direct summary like "yes, this is the case but there might exceptions depending if you want to execute another script from a file, via the heredoc-script itself".